# Integrating PayPal in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, paypal-sandbox

i have recently created a test paypal account, and also verified all the details, then i created the below form for testing the paypal integration. below is the code in placed in the file:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="aelectricwala52@gmail.com" />

    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="My painting" />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10.00" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Buy!" />

</form>
```

now when i pressed the buy button, i got the error saying:

```
This recipient is currently unable to receive money.
```

can anyone tell me what could be the issue, how can i resolve this.

Comment: Is `This recipient is currently unable to receive money.`  not very clear? Are you 100% sure the E-Mail address you show is a valid PayPal account? Can you send money to it from other accounts?

Comment: yes its the valid paypal, i just now created it and also able to login with this email id, so i am 100% sure its the valid paypal account, is there anything i need to configure to make it working

Comment: I think what Pekka is saying is, is the user that you created able to accept money yet. You have to attach your paypal to some sort of a bank account in order to accept money.

Comment: Logging in is one thing, but are you able to *send money to it*? That's the issue here, isn't it?

Comment: yes i have attached my hdfc bank account, but is still not verified, i got the mail that within 4-6 days they will deposit a small amount of money in my account which i need to confirm to verify my account, is that the issue, i am getting this error, or anything else i have missed, can anyone confirm whether my html above is correct, or @Pekka can you tell me how can i send money to this account, this is the test account.

Comment: i don't think you'll get rid of that error message until your bank account is confirmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> yes i have attached my hdfc bank account, but is still not verified, i got the mail that within 4-6 days they will deposit a small amount of money in my account which i need to confirm to verify my account

I can't find any official definite information, but I'm pretty sure this is your problem. Definitely wait for the verification amount to come through, and try again then.

> can you tell me how can i send money to this account, this is the test account.

You would need another PayPal account to send you a small amount of money, e.g. a friend's account.

Also, Googling the error message turns up more useful information like [this forum thread](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/How-to-use-PayPal/This-recipient-is-currently-unable-to-receive-money/td-p/19067) that deals with more possible reasons for the problem (but also stresses the need for your account to be verified.)

Comment: can you tell me does receiving payment requires the email address and password both, or just the email address, because i have just entered the email address in the above code. can you tell how to add the password parameter

Comment: @Abbas I'm not sure what you mean. The *sender* will need *their* E-Mail and password when sending money through that form (they need to log in to PayPal with their data.) *Your*, the recipient's, password is never needed. Never ever publish your password in a HTML form